# How I can reduce first input delay time for my website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am working on a web application (www.vokal.in). we are doing the server-side rendering. for my website, the first input delay is above 300. I want to reduce it to 100-150. How can I achieve that?

test URL:  https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vokal.in%2Fquestion%2F1JL23-kuch-aisa-kar-kamaal-ki-tera-ho-jaaun-main-kisi-aur-ka-hoon-filhal-ki-tera-ho-jaaun-kaun-si-film-ka-gaana-hai&hl=en&authuser=1

Comment: you need to provide more information this kinda questions has no certain answer.

Comment: Use a content delivery network (CDN) such as Amazon CloudFront (combined with Amazon S3) or Netlify.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share more detail about your problem,
In general, what you can do is?

Usually the main thread is predominantly blocked by parsing, compiling and executing JavaScript.

Also you can;

- Implement your own content delivery network (CDN).
- Use adaptive images.
- Cache,
- Combine images into CSS sprites.
- Enable HTTP keep-alive response headers.
- Compress your content.
- Configure expires headers.

After 
I think, you are going to get the better the results

---